# The Tolner Rebbe on donkeys and shofars

Tags: sources-mekorot, chasidut-hasidism, rosh-hashanah-new-year, shofar

[This article](https://torah.org/torah-portion/ravfrand-5778-nitzavim/) refers to a teaching of the Tolner Rebbe on [the Talmudic passage](https://www.sefaria.org/Rosh_Hashanah.28b.5?ven=William_Davidson_Edition_-_English&lang=bi) regarding one who mistakes the sound of the shofar for the sound of a donkey:

> The Tolner Rebbe asks – which Jew walks by a shul on Rosh Hashanna and
> hears the sounds of Tekiah Teruah Tekiah, etc. and thinks to himself
> “hmm – must be a donkey braying?” The first case of the Mishna is
> someone passing by outside a shul and he hears the shofar blowing.
> Fine. This is the case of a regular person. But the second case – “or
> his house is next door to the shul.” So, the question is – if his
> house is right next to the synagogue, why is he not coming to shul on
> Rosh Hashanah? What is he doing listening to the shofar from his
> house? The answer is that we are speaking about someone who has no
> interest in going to shul. This person is so far removed from Rosh
> Hashanah that when he hears the shofar blast, he thinks it might be a
> donkey braying. What kind of a Jew can think such a thing? The answer
> is we are speaking of a Jew who is that far away from proper behavior
> and thoughts on this holy day. Nevertheless, the Mishna is teaching us
> that “No!” If in one minute, he says “Hey! That is a shofar” then that
> recognition can lift him out of the dungeon. In that one minute, he
> can experience “from the trash heaps, He lifts up the destitute.”
> [Tehllim 113:7]

Does anyone know where this teaching comes from and where I can find the original? Thanks!